# help with simple order of operations in fractions?

Tags: fractions

first time poster here, so please be kind. :)

I am working on an issue that I can't see past.  I've got a worksheet with a multiple choice set of answers, but i KNOW they are all wrong! But maybe I am missing something?

It's a simple fraction to attempt to simplify the expression.

```
3/4 + 1/8 x 1/5
```

By my calculations, I am figuring the answer to be `31/40`, first by finding `1/8 x 1/5 = 1/40`, then adding `3/4 (30/40)`, which gives me `31/40`!

However, none of the multiple choices have that as an answer?

```
15/32, 30/7, 3/160, 6/5
```

Comment: I think your answer is correct, for the reasons you said.  What are the choices you have?

Comment: Yeah, it looks right to me. Tell us the multiple-choice options.

Comment: 15/32, 30/7, 3/160, 6/5

Thank you for getting back so quickly! None of these make sense to me except for 3/160, BUT that is only if we multiply ALL of them. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis is correct.  By the order of ops, + occurs last. × and / are parsed from left to right.

$$1/5×1/8 = (1/5)/8 = 1/40.$$